# Box Zoom - Fit to rectangle

Tags: c++, directx11

I want to box select a section of my screen and then zoom in that selection. So I have four corner points (my rectangle which I can drag with the mouse) in pixel coordinates. I have a perspective projection.

How can I create the camera view that has these four corner points as the corner points for the view? I guess that I have to calculate maybe a view frustum for my section?

Comment: Do you want to keep the current camera position and just rotate and zoom to get the desired view or do you want to keep the current front-vector and translate the camera to get to it?

Comment: Sounds like something that could probably be done by just moving the camera to point to the selection and adjusting scale based on the relative width and height of your viewport. It's not a neat solution though, calculating a frustum seems like a valid idea.

Comment: Hi. I have tried the solution of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545537/zoom-to-screen-space-selection-box-in-3d  but it doesn't work. I want to get the new camera position, which I should get by translation + zoom, but I have absolutely no idea how to do this correct. I have the coordinates of the rectangle in pixel coordinates e.g. (x0,y0) = (100,100) (x1,y1) = (200,300). And I want to zoom in to that rectangle. (Translating the camera so that the rectangle is in the center of the screen and then zoom in to that rectangle)

Comment: I'm not sure if you've figured out a solution to your problem yet (you should post it as an answer if you have) but I just wanted to say I'm working on this, though I may not be able to give you a complete answer for a couple of days (busy unfortunately).

Comment: I just figured a way out, but it has a problem. I have the new projection matrix already, but the new view matrix can´t be calulculated without knowing a distance to the camera to focus on. Heres an example (http://i.stack.imgur.com/HfJbf.png) you can´t get the translation without knowing the distance. The only way to do it is by rotation like they did in the link you posted.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I don't have found a solution yet.  @ParadoxicalReality: Would be nice if you can post your solution if you found a solution :)